# Storyboards segues and back

Tags: xcode, xcode6, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

I have two ViewControllers connected by a segue:
The first one has many TEXT FIELDs for user input and some LABELS to perform calculations. There is a button (storyboard segue) which send the user to the second Storyboard which has some pictures, in this second ViewController there is a button (storyboard segue) to bring back to the first ViewController.
When the user go back to the first ViewController all TEXT FIELDS/LABELs are blank.
The user will need to use the data in the first VC as many times he needs to go from VC1 to VC2 and back.
There is a button which will CLEAR ALL data when user wants perform another session, There is no need to keep the data after the app is closed.
Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a class to keep the data in global session.

```
class Session:NSObject {
    static var textfieldA = ""
    ...

    class func clearAll() {
        Session().textfieldA = ""
        ...
    }
}

// In VC1
// to set string
Session().textfieldA = "abc"
// to get string
anystring = Session().textfieldA
// to clear all
Session().clearAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `NSObject` class, and can save variables there, so that when you go to your first View Controller, you fetch the values from there and set them. Similarly, you can also use `NSUserDefaults` if you want to save them even if the app closes. Another way is to make `Singletons` and access them from anywhere. 
And if you will make a `Push Segue` then on back button you can `Pop` and Textfields data in the First View Controller will stay the same.

Comment: I think using NSUserDefaults would be overkill since @Manolo mentioned that there is no need to keep them after app closed.